# Parse Error while using ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a web application that was working fine two days before. When I moved this web site to another machine, then facing following problem.

In my web page, I have declared ScriptManager as:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptMgr" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

And when I visit the web page, I am getting this error:

```
The base class includes the field 'scriptMgr', but its type (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager).
```

And on another web page, I am getting following error:

```
The base class includes the field 'upProgress', but its type (System.Web.UI.UpdateProgress) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.UpdateProgress).
```

My web application is built on ASP.NET 2.0 and I have also verified that the correct(1.0.61025.0) version of System.Web.Extensions.Dll is present in my application's bin folder.

Entry for the System.Web.Extensions.Dll in the web.config are:

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
  <section name="CSI.OLS.Library.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
  <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
    <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
      <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
      <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

It seems that both the error are related to using AJAX feature. Can anyone tell me, what may be causing the aforementioned error?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't asp.net 2.0 need an extensions patch to correctly support ajax apps?

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/downloads/

Comment: I have already installed this patch. Still, I am facing error.

Comment: then please post your web.config

Comment: I have added the web.config entry, Please look into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a .NET 2.0 AJAX 1.0 vs .NET 3.5 AJAX issue.  (IE, the AJAX library was included directly in .NET 3.5 and it appears that you're trying to use the .NET 3.5 version of the AJAX libraries.)

I've encountered the same problem in an application and found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1160833.aspx) reference to the issue with two suggestions for solving the problem.

One suggestion is in your project file's reference to the System.Web.Extensions.dll assembly to set the *Specific Version* property to *True*.  Since you're explicitly referencing the 1.0.61025.0 version of this assembly, I suspect this would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

a late answer :) but I had a similar problem in my product and solved it by adding the following to web.config

```
<runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/></dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/></dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This redirects assembly binding so that the new version is used, therefore solving the conflicts